# LINQ query to query a list with array members

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I am trying to query a list using LINQ.

The query statement contains entries which should match items from an array.

In other words get entries from SourceList which match any one of the items from the items array.
Example:

```
private List<string> GetSearchResult(List<string> SourceList,
    string name, string[] items)
{
     IEnumerable<string> QueryList = SourceList.Where
         (entry => enrty.name == name && entry.id == <any item from items>)
}
```

I thought of building a query string looping though the items array.
I wanted to know if there is an efficient way of doing this.

Comment: sorry my mistake result is IEnumerable not List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private List<string> GetSearchResult(List<string> SourceList,string name, string[] items)
{
     return SourceList.Where(entry => entry.name == name && items.Contains(entry.id)).ToList();
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 4):

```
private List<string> GetSearchResult(List<string> SourceList,
    string name, string[] items)
{
     return SourceList.Where(entry => entry.name == name 
         && items.Contains(entry.id))
}
```

Comment: this will work, but if SourceList becomes a List<MyObject> you should think about implementing your own comparer. This will give you a way to customize your compare, for example X.Id == Y.Id.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
private List<string> GetSearchResult(List<string> SourceList,string name, string[] items)
{
     List<string> QueryList = SourceList.Where
                     (entry => enrty.name == name && items.Any(m => m == entry.id.ToString()))
}
```